# how to set progress from a string?

Tags: android, progress-bar

i am trying to display the output of these two methods in my progress bar. but for that i would need to do the "long" output for both of them. what is the correct way of doing this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView ttvv1;
    TextView ttvv2;
    TextView ttvv3;
    private ProgressBar pb3; // *

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ttvv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        ttvv1.setText(getTotalRAM());
        ttvv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        freeMem();
        pb3 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1); // *

        pb3.setMax((int) availableMegs); // *
        pb3.setProgress(getTotalRAM); // *

    }

    private void freeMem() {
        MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
        long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
        ttvv2.setText(availableMegs + " MB");

    }

    private String getTotalRAM() {
        RandomAccessFile reader = null;
        String load = null;
        long total = 0;
        try {
            reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/meminfo", "r");
            load = reader.readLine().replaceAll("\\D+", "");
            total = Integer.parseInt(load) / 1024;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return total + " MB";
    }

}
```

this is basically my approach, but i am getting errors- **getTotalRAM cannot be resolved to a variable** and **availableMegs cannot be resolved to a variable**

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView ttvv1;
    TextView ttvv2;
    TextView ttvv3;
    private ProgressBar pb3; // *

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ttvv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        ttvv1.setText("" + getTotalRAM());
        ttvv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        int availableMegs = freeMem();
        pb3 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1); // *

       // pb3.setMax(availableMegs); // *
        pb3.setProgress(getTotalRAM() * 100/availableMegs); // *

    }

    private void freeMem() {
        MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
        long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
        ttvv2.setText(availableMegs + " MB");
        return (int)availableMegs;
    }

    private int getTotalRAM() {
        RandomAccessFile reader = null;
        String load = null;
        long total = 0;
        try {
            reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/meminfo", "r");
            load = reader.readLine().replaceAll("\\D+", "");
            total = Integer.parseInt(load) / 1024;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (int)total;
    }

}
```

Comment: it is not error free, please test it and edit. thanks

Comment: Changed getTotalRAM to return int.

Comment: it is force closing because of this line being called in the oncreate "ttvv1.setText(getTotalRAM());"

Comment: but i want to display ram in textview also. only one textview is working now with the progress bar

Comment: wait actually no!. it always sets my progress bar full!

Comment: getTotalRAM() is a int , so you should ttvv1.setText("" + getTotalRAM()).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be declaring and initializing `availableMegs` from inside the `freeMem` method. As a result, calling that variable from outside that method will result in an error (Methods don't inherit variables declared in other methods). If you plan to use `availableMegs` between multiple methods, you can either declare/initialize it in `onCreate` and pass it to the methods that need it, or you can make it a global variable.

For your `getTotalRam` String, it looks like you're missing a pair of parentheses after the method call. Change `pb3.setProgress(getTotalRam);` to `pb3.setProgress(getTotalRam());`. Passing it to `setText` as you've specified means the application will look for a variable called getTotalRam, which of course isn't present.

Remember that regardless of what return type a method is (In this case a String), you always need to specify that that it's a method (not a variable) by including the parentheses, even if there are no parameters being passed to it.

If you need a `long` variable to pass to a progress bar, you definitely don't want to cast it to an `int`. Your line `pb3.setMax((int) availableMegs);` seems counter-productive. Once you've declared `availableMegs` as a `long` in the appropriate place (as specified above), you'll want to keep it as a `long`, since that's what your progress bar requires.

Hope this helps!